# Wireless adapters no longer interfacable

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, network-adapter, network-interface, hostapd

In the process of setting up a server I followed these two tutorials:

https://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd

https://community.openhab.org/t/setup-your-own-openhab-cloud-myopenhab-server-instance/24716

I have two network adapters. 1 is used to connect to the router which is connected to the internet. 2 is used to for a private home server. They were both working until I restarted my computer (after following the tutorials)

They are both detected with `lsusb` and `lspci` respectively. `ip link show` shows only the second adapter, the first is missing entirely.

Trying to start the private network host with `sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: driver initialization failed.
wlp3s0: interface state UNINITIALIZZED->DISABLED
wlp3s0: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlp3s0 wasn't started
```

If I removed the changes I added to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet static
hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

So that `/etc/network/interfaces` now reads

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then I can use this adapter to connect to the internet router. It gives the same error message when I try to start hostapd.

I need to start hostapd to host the private network, and I need to get the 1st network adapter working at all. I suppose something must have changed in the tutorial 2 process that broke interfacing with my wifi adapters.

UPDATE: As part of the tutorial process I `sudo apt upgrade`. That broke the driver for the internet card, which I reinstalled and is now working.

I think the problem with the private network card is also a driver issue. Looking in `/var/log/apt/history.log` I find:

```
Start-Date: 2019-03-31  11:38:05
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: test (1000)
Install: irqbalance:amd64 (1.1.0-2.3, automatic), firmware-linux-free:amd64 (3.4, automatic), linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64:amd64 (4.9.144-3.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-amd64:amd64 (4.9+80+deb9u2, 4.9+80+deb9u6), tzdata:amd64 (2018i-0+deb9u1, 2019a-0+deb9u1)
End-Date: 2019-03-31  11:38:46
```

The firmware-linux-free package contains drivers for the not-working card, but uninstalling it has had no effect on my interaction with that card.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Super User. It's good that you posted links to the tutorial for context. In addition to the links, it would help us answer your question if you edited the question to add a step by step list of what you actually did and what results you got. This way, you save the people trying to help you time and if the problem is that you made a mistake following the instructions, it will become apparent.

Comment: That is what I remove. Those changes were committed in tutorial 1. I'll try to put together the comprehensive list of the things I did. The remaining code is

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback